# Usage of "scared," "fear of," "afraid of/to," and "concerned to"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, vocabulary

Could anybody please explain me when can I use 'afraid', 'fear of', 'scared', 'concern', 'worried' to express a situation that i can't handle or out of my reach? Explain also please which one of the terms above get the highest extent in expressing the worst situation. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This problem actually lies in the words you choose to use after these words.

> - I am **afraid** that I will ruin the relationship.
> - I **fear** that I will ruin the relationship.
> - I'm **scared** that I will ruin the relationship.
> - I'm **concerned** about ruining the relationship.
> - I'm **worried** that I will ruin the relationship.

These all have very close meanings aside from the extent to which they describe your mental state, and they can all easily be used to form the sentence or phrase you're looking for.

As for which is best for the worst situation, this is a bit of an opinion. I tend to consider fear the base of most of the words you listed. Without fear, you can't be afraid or scared. So I would say using *fear* in the sentence/phrase is your best option.